# how can i divide two eval variables

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

i tried and get the sum of two numbers by getting through eval

```
<%# Convert.ToDecimal(Eval("total"))+ Convert.ToDecimal(Eval("tax")) %>
```

by doing this i got the sum of (total + tax)
now i need to find the division. Is it possible to divide like `<%# Convert.ToDecimal(Eval("total"))/ Convert.ToDecimal(Eval("qty")) %>` the above. 
my code in detail

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td class="text-left"><%#Eval("rowId") %></td>
            <td><%#Eval("product_name") %> - <%#Eval("product_des") %></td>
            <td class="text-center"><%#Eval("qty") %></td>
            <td class="text-center"><%#Eval("uom") %></td>
            <td class="text-center"><%#Eval("tax_percent") %></td>
            <td class="text-right"><%# Convert.ToDouble(Convert.ToDecimal(Eval("total"))/ Convert.ToDecimal(Eval("qty")))%></td>
            <td class="text-right"><%# Convert.ToDecimal(Eval("total"))+ Convert.ToDecimal(Eval("tax")) %></td>
            <td class="text-center"><%#Eval("type") %></td>
            <td class="text-right">
                <asp:ImageButton ID="ibtnEdit" runat="server" ImageUrl="assets/btn/edit_btn.png" OnClick="ibtnEdit_Click" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("rowId") %>' />
                <asp:ImageButton ID="ibtn_Delete" runat="server" ImageUrl="assets/btn/delete_btn.png" OnClick="ibtn_Delete_Click" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("rowId") %>' OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?');" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

please help me. thanks in advance

Comment: Why are you asking this question? There are no differences between the arithmetic operators. Have you encountered a problem? It's impossible to help if you don't mention what the actual problem is

Comment: BTW the operators deal with *decimals*, not Eval. If you encounter a problem is because `Eval` failed or the returned text isn'd a number

Comment: i didn't get the resultant value after performing this operation.

Comment: there is no problems encountered.

Comment: Don't get the results =  problem. Otherwise we can just delete this question. What *are* the underlying values? Numbes, text, empty spaces, zeroes? Do you get an empty cell? A missing row?